# can't save changes to Makefile on Fedora 19

Tags: linux, fedora, permission-denied, ns2

So I'm installing NS2.35 on my Fedora 19

per this link - http://wpage.unina.it/marcello.caleffi/ns2/fedora.html

Now everything about this installation is going smoothly but I'm hitting a snag when it comes to cut/copy/paste/save as activities .

Specifically , when I tried to

1) copy a folder and paste it into another directory like in Windows it said permissions denied . However I found a command online that allowed me to extract to a destination directory instead of current so that's fine.

My problem presently is that after "step 4" in the link posted above , the author says I've to make changes to the "Makefile" - I have made the necessary changes but I'm not able to "save" the changed file .

The option is grayed out .

I'm new to Linux but I know that this step requires super user permission . I typed in "su" on the terminal and tried doing it but to no success .

Please help another n00b out .

Comment: Was the `su` command successful?  Does the terminal prompt start with `root` instead of your login user name now?

Comment: Yes , it changed to root . Using "sudo gedit filename" fixed it . However , I have no idea why "sudo nautilus " doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type **su** in terminal and type the root password. now open Makefile by using **gedit Makefile** in Terminal. now you can modify your Makefile. hope it helps

Comment: Naveen , sudo nautilus should also work ? (Came across that in a few sources online , however it crashes when I try it )

Comment: Also , are you familiar with NS2 installation procedure , installed ns2 successfully however ran into what seems to be a C++ language error while trying to install "xgraph"

Comment: I fixed it . Had to find a newer rpm version.